# How to see the assembly language in code-blocks?

Tags: assembly, codeblocks

In visual C++ , we can see the converted assembly language. How do I do It in code blocks? If it's not possible in code-blocks then How do I do it in Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugger breaks in C++ source line, select Debug - Debugging Windows - Disassembly to see Assembly code.

Of course, without Code::Blocks, you can use classic gdb or some gdb GUI wrapper, like KDbg.